# git bash freezes when I run "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, git-bash

I'm trying to learn django and have already created my project using startproject. Now I want to run the server but it won't work in git bash. It works if I use powershell or cmd but it just freezes in git bash. It says "Watching for file changes with StatReloader" but does nothing. Please help I want to use git bash to run my commands. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to run it in git bash? Why not the regular powershell or cmd?

Comment: I'm used to it, and I don't understand why it doesn't work. It did a couple months ago when I started a django course and it's weird that it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Django auto reloading feature is recent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55831728/6309): make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (v2.25.0-rc0.windows.1) to see if the issue persists in a git bash session.

If this is based on inotify to do file watching... that [might not be compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517460/6309) with [mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32356595/6309).