# Why am I seeing message for Unapplied Migration(s) after Upgrading Django from 2.0 to 2.2

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-upgrade

I upgraded Django from version 2.0 to 2.2. The upgrade completed without any issue. However trying to start the server issues the following message:

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing system
> checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> You have 3 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
> until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth. Run 'python
> manage.py migrate' to apply them.
>
> March 27, 2021 - 08:37:07 Django version 2.2.19, using settings
> 'lead.settings' Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

My application so far is working fine as before (i.e. prior to upgrade).

I have checked the database in migrations table but fine no entry for the reference date. There are also no migration file/s in the app's "migrations" folder.

My question is:

What are these migrations the system is pointing to? Will it be prudent to go ahead and apply the migrations?

Additionally, I am not sure I have come across the following entry at the beginning before the upgrade:

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Has it something to with the upgrade?

**Update**

Got some information about the second part of my question i.e. StatReloader [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831728/what-is-statreloader-while-running-django). So I presume a Django installation starting with version 2.2 onwards will have this *feature*. (I failed to come up with this info may be because I was adding the key word *migration* in the search phrase and the info would be relegated to subs pages.)

Now hopefully I will get some answer to my primary query about the **migration(s)**.

Comment: Just migrate without worries. From the message: _Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth._. It is not a change in your apps, it is a change in the admin and auth apps from Django itself. Looking at the code in GitHub there doesn't seem to be any breaking changes (except perhaps `0011_update_proxy_permissions.py` in the `auth` app seems to have some change that might give a warning if failed)

Comment: Thanks. Going ahead with migrations. Will update the results.

Comment: Migrations completed without a problem. The app so far working fine.